# Libtorrent Get File by Merkle hash

Tags: bittorrent, libtorrent

How can I request file knowing its Merkle hash via libtorrent? I'll be glad to see a piece of code or maybe just description of the logic. Do I need to download .torrent file based on the Merkle hash

Comment: Which feature of the bittorrent protocol do you have in mind?

Comment: @the8472 I want one PC was able to download a file from another knowing the file Merkle root hash. They both know each other IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are two BEPs definining merkle-tree based torrents. [BEP30](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0030.html) and [BEP52](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0052.html). Neither enables sharing a file based on its merkle hash alone as they require some additional data to build a minimal viable torrent such as the piece size or the file size. To support multiple files, file names and other things some additional metadata is needed which ultimately gets encapsulated in the infohash. So torrent clients generally deal in infohashes, not file hashes.

You can bypass some of these requirements by choosing a fixed filename and fixed piece size and then generate a canonical metadata representation for your file. In libtorrent that could be done through the [create_torrent()](http://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Create_Torrents.html#create_torrent) API by creating a v2-only torrent (BEP52 without backwards compatibility).

Comment: So file path, file size, and BEP52 Merkle Root hash is enough for downloading the file?

Comment: In the general case: No. The torrent info dictionary can contain arbitrary additional data, that's why the info hash is used. Only in specially crafted cases where you control the torrent creation on both ends you can use a restricted subset of the metadata.